# How to draw a circular "arc"ed double distance arrow with correctly positioned tips and text with graphics between the double distance lines?

Tags: tikz-arrows, decorations, text-decorations

I have a problem with the position of an arrow tip when drawing a circular double distance arrow.
Problem seems to be the use of library bending or not. If not, partly correctly positioned tips, but problems with width option (why to use different widths. that is no way to go) and differing lines of the arc in calendar year 1 and 2. Very confusing and no solution in sight. Also I cannot find a way to combine the text decorations, which are not placed suitably in the arrows, with arrows. Is that the way to go? All what I get are syntax errors. In hope I could make the idea clear:

1. correctly formed arrows with tips (open and filling should be possible).
2. "baselined" text in the mentioned arrows.
3. use of additional graphics, such as a bend arrow (faked here by ----->), in the added text

Any, perhaps completely other, idea to solve that would be very appreciated!

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
                    % bending, % for arrows. 
                    calc,
                    arrows.meta, % for the tip in skorpio
                    decorations,
                    decorations.pathreplacing,
                    decorations.pathmorphing,
                    decorations.text,
                    decorations.markings, % arrow tips on a circle
                   }
    \usepackage[paperheight=160mm,
                paperwidth=180mm,
                top=5mm,
                bottom=5mm,
                left=5mm,
                right=5mm,
                %showframe
               ]{geometry}
    \begin{document}
    
    \def\radiustropy{35mm} % tropical year radius 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{shape ty/.style= {color = black!30,
                               draw,
                               %fill = yellow!30,
                               line width = 1pt,
                               inner xsep = 2.5cm,
                               inner ysep = 0.5cm},
            }% end tikzset shape ty
    \node[name=ty,shape=circle,shape ty] {Circle\vrule width 1pt height 2cm};
    
    
    % to cover the edge of ty (future use)
    \node[draw,blue,, line width=3mm,name=c,shape=circle,minimum size=\radiustropy*2-3mm] at (ty.center){};
    
    
    % 
    %tropical year, full circle
    \draw [->,draw=red!10!black!60!white,,
            double distance=1ex,
            line width=1pt,
            -{Stealth[width=10pt,red!10!black!60!white,open,scale=1.0]}
            % doesn't work % % arrows={Stealth[red!10!black!60!white,open,bend,scale=1.0]}
    ]%% 
    (0:\radiustropy) arc [start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=\radiustropy];
    
    % text, long, up to halfcircle       
    \path%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
                  decoration={raise=-1pt,%
                  text along path, %
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]A tropical year lasts 365 days, 5 hours 48 minutes und 45.2 seconds and begins and ends here -----------> [] },
                  text align={align=center}
                             }%
                 }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy);    
    
    \path [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-3pt,text along path,%
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]A tropical year lasts 365 days, 5 hours 48 minutes und 45.2 seconds [] },
    %reverse path,
     text align={align=}
    }}](180:\radiustropy) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy);             
    
    
    
    
    % first calendar year
    
    \draw [->,draw=red!30!black!40!white,
            -{Stealth[red!30!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}
    ]%
    (0,0) -- (350:\radiustropy+17); %
    
    
    % help to set begin of second year
    \node[inner sep=0,draw,blue,,name=bsy,circle,minimum size=.3pt]at(4.038,-0.713){};
    
    
    \draw [->,draw=red!30!black!40!white,,
            double distance=1.5ex,
            line width=1pt,
            -{Stealth[width=12pt,red!30!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}
    ]%% 
    (0:\radiustropy+2.5mm) arc [start angle=0, end angle=350, radius=\radiustropy+2.5mm];
    
    % text, long, up to halfcircle       
    \draw%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
                  decoration={raise=-1.5pt,%
                  text along path, %
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]A calendar year lasts 365 days [] },
                  %reverse path,
                  text align={align=center}
                             }%
                 }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy-2.5mm,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy+2.5mm);    
    
    \draw [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5pt,text along path,%
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]First calendar year, 5 hours 48 minutes und 45.2 seconds too less [] },
     text align={align=}
    }}](180:\radiustropy+2.5mm) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy+2.5mm);             
    
     
    
    % second calendar year
    
     \draw [->,draw=red!60!black!20!white,
            -{Stealth[red!60!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}
    ]%
    (0,0) -- (340:\radiustropy+17);
    
    
    \draw [->,draw=red!60!black!20!white,,
            double distance=1.5ex,
            line width=1pt,
            -{Stealth[width=13pt,red!60!black!20!white,open,scale=1.0]}
    ]%% 
    %(4.038,-0.713) 
    (bsy) arc [start angle=-10, end angle=340, radius=\radiustropy+6mm];
    % text, long, up to halfcircle       
    \draw%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
                  decoration={raise=-1.5pt,%
                  text along path, %
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]Some comment about tje second year e.g. dec values of the hours [] },
                  %reverse path,
                  text align={align=center}
                             }%
                 }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy-6mm,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy+6mm);    
    
    \draw [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5pt,text along path,%
                  text format delimiters={[}{]},
                  text={[\tiny]Second calendar year, 10 hours 96 minutes und 90.4 seconds too less [] },
    %reverse path,
     text align={align=}
    }}](180:\radiustropy+6mm) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy+6mm);             
    
     
    % a grid
    \draw[step=.1cm,gray!50!white,very thin] (0,-1) grid (5,5);
    \draw[step=1cm,black!40!red, very thin,opacity=0.4] (0,-1) grid (5,5);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0,4,5}
       \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1,5}
       \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {\tiny$\ytext$};
    % end grid
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your sophisticated knowhow I solve

1. the deviation of circled arcs, - eliminated
2. text with Umlaute in the arrows (SI units like 2d 3h 4 min not possible?)
3. correct positioning of an arrowtip (by means of a pic)

This solution is a basic approach, but with handwork fulfills the requirements.

mwe:

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{
            % bending, % for arrows. 
            calc,
            arrows.meta, % for the tip in skorpio
            decorations,
            decorations.pathreplacing,
            decorations.pathmorphing,
         decorations.text,
            decorations.markings, % arrow tips on a circle
           }
    \usepackage[paperheight=160mm,
        paperwidth=180mm,
        top=5mm,
        bottom=5mm,
        left=5mm,
        right=5mm,
        %showframe
       ]{geometry}

    %\input{/home/hj/latex/mwes/pics/arrowtip/inparrowtip.tex}

    % def of an arrow tip
    %\draw[yshift=-0.1,rotate=45,scale=0.5,blue,line width=0.1,fill=green] (0,0) -- (0.15,-0.4)
    %                                       -- (0,-0.3)
    %                                       -- (-0.15,-0.4) -- cycle
    %;
    \tikzset{pics/atip/%
     .style n args={6}{
           code={
                 \draw[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5,#6] 
                      (0,0) -- (0.18,-0.45)
                            -- (0,-0.3)
                            -- (-0.18,-0.45) -- cycle
                 ;
                  }%end code
                  },%end pic
    }%end tikzset
    \begin{document}

    \def\radiustropy{35mm} % tropical year radius 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{shape ty/.style= {color = black!30,
                       draw,
                       %fill = yellow!30,
                       line width = 1pt,
                       inner xsep = 2.5cm,
                       inner ysep = 0.5cm},
    }% end tikzset shape ty
    \node[name=ty,shape=circle,shape ty] {Circle\vrule width 1pt height 2cm};


    % to cover the edge of ty (future use)
    \node[draw,blue,, line width=3mm,name=c,shape=circle,minimum size=\radiustropy*2-3mm] at (ty.center){};


    % 
    %tropical year, full circle
    %
    % rotate=-6.1 atip1
    \pic at (0:\radiustropy+0.75ex) {atip={yshift=-0.5}{rotate=-5}{scale=1.00}{black!75}{line width=0.4}{fill=white!100!black!75}};
 
    % border of circled info text 1i
    % start line
    \draw[,black,line width=0.4,] (\radiustropy-0,0) -- (\radiustropy+1.5ex,0);      
    \draw[,black,line width=0.4,] (\radiustropy-0,0) arc (0:353:\radiustropy-0);      
    % border of circled info text 1a
    \draw[,black,line width=0.4,] (\radiustropy+1.5ex,0) arc (0:354:\radiustropy+1.5ex);
    \path%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
          decoration={raise=1.35pt,%
          text along path, %
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]TJ1 u. KJ1 beginnen synchron [] },
          %reverse path,
          text align={align=center}
                     }%
         }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy);    

    \path [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-4.6pt,text along path,%
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]KJ1 endet 5,8125 Std zu fr{\"u}h [] },
     text align={align=}
    }}](180:\radiustropy) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy);             

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % second calendar year
    %
    \draw [->,draw=red!30!black!40!white,
    -{Stealth[red!30!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}
    ]%
    (0,0) -- (350:\radiustropy+7mm); %
    % help to set begin of second year
    \draw [] (3.95,-0.695) -- (4.038,-0.713) -- (4.126,-0.73); %

    \draw [->,draw=red!30!black!40!white,
    -{Stealth[red!30!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}
  ]%
       (0,0) -- (343:\radiustropy+5mm); % 
    % second year
    
    \pic at (350:\radiustropy+6.0mm) {atip={yshift=-0.5}{rotate=-10.0}{scale=1.00}{black!75}{line width=0.4}{fill=white!100!black!75}};
 
 
    % border of circled info text 2i
    \draw[,black,line width=0.4,] (3.95,-0.695) arc (-10:344:\radiustropy+5mm);      
    % border of circled info text 2a
    \draw[,black,line width=0.4,] (4.126,-0.73) arc (-10:345:\radiustropy+7.15mm);
    \path%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
          decoration={raise=0.00pt,%
          text along path, %
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]TJ1 u. KJ1 beguuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuinnen synchron [] },
          %reverse path,
          text align={align=center}
                     }%
         }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy-5.5mm,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy+5.5mm);    

    \path [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-3.3pt,text along path,%
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]KJ1 endet 10,8125 Std zu fr{\"u}h [] },
     text align={align=}
    }}](-\radiustropy-5.5mm,0) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy+5.5mm);             

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % third calendar year
    \draw [->,draw=red!60!black!20!white,-{Stealth[red!60!black!40!white,open,scale=1.0]}] 
       (0,0) -- (340:\radiustropy+11.0mm);

    % third year
    \pic at (340:\radiustropy+11.0mm) {atip={yshift=-0.5}{rotate=-20.0}{scale=1.00}{black!75}{line width=0.4}{fill=white!100!black!75}};
 
    % border of circled info text 3i
    \draw[line width=0.4,] (340:\radiustropy+10mm) arc (-20:334.5:\radiustropy+10mm);      
    % border of circled info text 3a
    \draw[line width=0.4,] (340:\radiustropy+12.25mm) arc (-20:335:\radiustropy+12.25mm);
    \path%
    [%
     postaction={decorate,%
          decoration={raise=-1.50pt,%
          text along path, %
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]KJ3 beguuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuinnen synchron [] },
          %reverse path,
          text align={align=center}
                     }%
         }%
    ]
    (-\radiustropy-11mm,0) arc (180:0:\radiustropy+11mm);    

    \path [,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.0pt,text along path,%
          text format delimiters={[}{]},
          text={[\tiny]KJ3 ca. 18 std diff to year 1 [] },
     text align={align=}
    }}](-\radiustropy-11mm,0) arc (-180:0:\radiustropy+11mm);             
    %start third year
    \draw [] (340:\radiustropy+10mm) -- (340:\radiustropy+12.25mm);

    % a grid
    %\draw[step=.05cm,blue!50!white,very thin] (3,-1.5) grid (5,1.5);
    \draw[step=.1cm,gray!50!white,very thin] (0,-1) grid (5,5);
    \draw[step=1cm,black!40!red, very thin,opacity=0.4] (0,-1) grid (5,5);
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0,4,5}
       \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {\tiny$\xtext$};
    \foreach \y/\ytext in {1,5}
       \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {\tiny$\ytext$};
    % end grid
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]